# why border color will transform to hex from rgba in postcss

Tags: vite, postcss

`border-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 70%)` will transform to `border-color: #000000b3`
And it will be #000000 in some devices.
Why postcss do this transform default in vite.
Is there any idea?